# How to get content from Google Drive to Evernote?

Tags: google-drive, evernote, google-keep, zapier

I want to transfer my Google Keep notes to Evernote. Because Zapier doesn't support Google Keep yet, what I wanted to do is use the "Copy to Docs" option within Google Keep to export my notes to Google Drive first. Google Drive is supported by Zapier, so I can then set a trigger to export to Evernote (creating a new note) when a new file is created in Google Drive.

What I want to do is copy the entire content of a newly created Google Drive file into Evernote. How do I do that? Getting the title isn't a problem, but somehow I'm having trouble pinpointing how to export the entire content of the new Google Drive file into Evernote. All I can do is put the content of the Google Drive file as an attachment to the new Evernote file, which is not what I want, I want the content to be exported into the note itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a helpful site. Almost as helpful as World Building.

The problem was I should've chosen Google Docs as the trigger app, but I had Google Drive selected. So there was no way for Zapier to get the content into an Evernote note because it couldn't be sure that the file was really a document, and not a sheet or an image.